# SQL - Return amalgamated row of most recent content from matching rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I can't figure this out - I guess it's simple but I can't find a suitable method.

I believe it's called the 'Last non-null puzzle', but I can't follow the solutions online! At the moment I'm using PHP to parse through a returned array until variables are all full, but I'd prefer to do it in SQL. Using MariaDB 8 on Ubuntu.

ID increments as records are added. It could be a datetime.

If I have the following:

```
ID | Data1 | Data2 | Data3
1  | NULL  | Book  | NULL
2  | Pink  | NULL  | Cat
3  | NULL  | Book  | NULL
4  | Blue  | NULL  | NULL
5  | NULL  | Stool | Cat
6  | White | NULL  | NULL
7  | NULL  | NULL  | Bull
```

How would I return: `White | Stool | Bull` (the most 'recent' non-NULLs)?

Is there a way to select on `id = '4'` and return `Blue | Book | Cat`?

I've been trying for hours! I've seen some posts on amalgamation but those don't seem to apply. Sorry of this is trivial - I assume it is but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please tag with database flavor.  Also do not understand the underlying logic you are asking for.  What is "most recent?"  There is no date.  You need to provide more of an explanation.

Comment: Updated. Thank you

Comment: There is no MariaDB 8. What does `select version()` say;

Comment: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3

Answer (score 0):

please check the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT Data1 FROM test t2
 WHERE Data1 IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
) Data1,

(SELECT Data2 FROM test t2
 WHERE Data2 IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
) Data2,

(SELECT Data3 FROM test t3
 WHERE Data3 IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
) Data3
```

Comment: You are better off putting the subqueries directly in the `SELECT`, just in case some columns have only `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effective values on each row using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(data1) over (partition by grp1) as imputed_data1,
       max(data2) over (partition by grp2) as imputed_data2,
       max(data3) over (partition by grp3) as imputed_data3
from (select t.*,
             count(data1) over (order by id) as grp1,
             count(data2) over (order by id) as grp2,
             count(data3) over (order by id) as grp3
      from t
     ) t;
```

You can then see the values for all `id` or some `id`s or the last row by using this as a subquery or CTE.